# How do you config Google Cloud Platform for european server ?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot

When I do google cloud platform tutorial to deploy a spring boot java web app
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-springboot

I get stuck with the following error :

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Flexible Environment deployments are not supported in the apps region 'europe-west'.
```

Is there a way to not use the Flexible Environment deployments (or to make it works). I cannot even find other possible values for the yaml file

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always  # Require HTTPS
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [App Engine Locations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations):

> **Note:** The **europe-west** region only supports the [standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment). You must select a different region to use the
>   [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).

So you have 2 alternatives:

- use an alternate GAE-offering region, I'd choose **us-east1**
- see if you can convert your app to use the standard environment instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went for the first solution. I was able to get a clean starting project from their maven archetypes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your region to US West, run this:

```
gcloud config set compute/region us-west1
```